# Intercept workbook save event and append string to end of workbook filename

Tags: excel, vba

I know how to intercept a workbook's save event by doing this at module level:

```
Dim WithEvents app As Application

Private Sub app_WorkbookBeforeSave(ByVal Wb As Workbook, ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)


End Sub
```

What I'd like to do is append a string to the end of the actual filename.  For example, if I save with the name `Sales.xls`, I would like to automatically be able to add `_extract` to the end so that the name is `Sales_extract.xls`, but I can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: Hmm maybe a workaround where you ask user for saveas name via an inputbox then do something like `activeworkbook.saveas filename:= [inputboxvariable] & "_extract" then activeworkbook.close`?

Answer (score 1):

Put this in your sub

```
Dim myFileName As String
myFileName = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Split(myFileName, ".")(0) & "test." & Split(myFileName, ".")(1)
```

Change the "test." to anything you want but make sure it ends with a "."

Answer (score 1):

You can intercept the event from within ThisWorkbook module:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

    Const CUSTOM_NAME As String = "_extract"

    Dim fn As String

    fn = Me.Name
    If InStr(fn, ".") > 0 Then fn = Left(fn, InStrRev(fn, ".") - 1)

    Cancel = Not Right(fn, Len(CUSTOM_NAME)) = CUSTOM_NAME

    If Cancel Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        'Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Me.SaveAs Me.Name & "_extract" & Right(Me.Name, InStrRev(Me.Name, ".") - 1)
        'Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```